# Visual Studio Win32 C++ Project very slow when Linking

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio, linker

I have a Win32 application developed in VS2015 (C++) that has a fairly large executable resource embedded in it.

The embedded resource is about 500mb in size, and there are some other executable resources embedded taking the total size when built up to about 700Mb.

The Win32 app is simply a bootstrapper that detects whether the .Net framework is installed and if not it installs it so that the main executable payload can be extracted and launched. So the C++ app itself is quite small - just has a large payload.

Anyway...

If I build the C++ app without the embedded resources it takes a few seconds to build.

When I build the C++ app with all the resources present it takes 45 minutes to build!

My dev machine spec is i7 quad core CPU, 16Gb RAM with twin 128Gb SSDs that are in RAID 1 giving a disk read/write speed of about 1Gb/s.

It seems that the linker is giving me the problem, when I build the app it fairly quickly compiles and outputs "Finished pass 2". it then sits there for 45 minutes doing the linking.

I notice that in Task Manager my disk I/O is maxed out as 100%, but the average read/write speed is around 800k/s (nowhere near even plain old SATA speed let alone striped SSDs.).

Have tried disabling AV software, but am not sure where else to look?

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can speed up the linking time for these large resources?

Thanks

Comment: Strange it seems to be working fine now! I changed the linker to NOT use incremental linking and it builds in about 20 seconds now. However if I revert the linker setting back to what it was it still builds in 20 seconds :-$

Comment: Bah. After it had started working properly I had to do a reboot. Now it's back to being slow again and no matter how I tweak the linker options I can't get the performance back again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was something to do with my C: drive (2 x striped SSDs). When I set the project to output to my D: drive (plain old SATA HDD) the build time went back to being about 30 seconds.

So looks like an issue with my HDD controller. Strange that it doesn't affect any other builds that I do, just the one with the large embedded resources.